# Adding delete button (unlink) to uploaded files

Tags: php, unlink

I have made a file upload form so that logged in users can upload files to a custom folder (uploads/users/username/).

The code below shows all the files the user has uploaded, however, I've been struggling to add a 'delete' button for each item. This is a tightly controlled website with no registration and is not for the public domain, so security isn't an enormous issue since this will only be used by 15-20 users at most.

I've been struggling to neatly add in the unlink. I've tried various suggestions found online but with no luck, I think it should look something like:

```
<?php
$dir_open = opendir('uploads/users/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '');
while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
            $fullpath = "uploads/users/" . $_SESSION['username'] . "/$filename";
            echo "<a href='$fullpath' target=\"_blank\"><img src='$fullpath' style='width:350px;border: 1px solid #000;'></a><br />
                  $filename<br />
Delete button-->  <a href="$fullpath">Delete file</a>
                  <hr><br />";
}}closedir($dir_open);
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To create a delete button for each file, you need to get the id and the path to the file, assuming you've stored that info in the db when you created the upload functionality. So the example could look like:

```
<?php
//...
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name','db_user','db_pass');
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,filename FROM your_table');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
?>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Then, in `delete.php` file:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    //db connect here
    $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']);
}
```

Regarding security, I can't tell you much about, as I don't know exactly what you want. But you can check for the mime type (and allow only mime types you want), and about file sizes (to allow only certain file sizes, or disallow 0-sized files). Just search google, there are plenty of good tutorials about this subject.

And for listing all uploaded files, for each user, you can use the db too.

**LE**

Ok, I dug a little bit about your problem, and I finally found a way to let your users remove files. But be aware that I didn't took into account any sort of security. That's your responsibility, even though you have this question too.

So the code looks like this:

```
//index.php
$files = scandir('files');
foreach ($files as $file){
    if (is_file('files/'.$file)){
        ?>
        <a href="index.php?remove=<?php echo $file; ?>">delete</a> <br>
        <?php
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
    unlink('files/'.$_GET['remove']) ? header('Location: index.php') : print 'Not Removed<br>';
}
```

I used a `chmod 777 -R files/` before trying the code. I really don't know if this is a good approach.

**LE2**

The directory structure I've used for this example:

```
project/
    files/
         1.php
         2.html
         3.css
         4.js
    index.php
```

Those files (`1.php`, `2.html`, etc) are placed there by your upload functionality, you've said you already have.
`index.php` will, first of all, read that `files/` directory as an array (containing only the file names); then will iterate through the array, and check if each element of the array is a file, and if it is, then will generate a link, and redirecting the user back to the `index.php`, but this time having a query string (eg: `index.php?remove=1.php`). Then, the last check questions if there is a query string named `remove`, and if there is one, it will delete the respective file and will redirect back to `index.php`.

Comment: Hi Dan, I already have the full filepath in '$fullpath'. I'm not using a db for the files hence why I believe 'unlink()' is the way to go with this. I have a similar setup I use at home on my intranet and that uses a pre-built system with a db to handle all logins/files and works fine, however, isn't suitable in this case as the website I'm working on is restricted to one db and is already being used. I'm aware this can be done without a db but I've read every single result on the first 5 pages of Google and none of those help with this circumstance.

Comment: @noozl Take a look at my LE.

Comment: I still can't implement that with my current code. I'm not that great with PHP so I'm struggling with this a little. Any pointers in where to place what?

Comment: @noozl check my LE2 please.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is make sure that when saving the file, you create a unique name to save the file by changing the file name to something of such

```
<?php
    $fileExtension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = uniqid('upload_') . rand(10000,9999999) . 
                date('ymdHis') . rand(10000,9999999) . '.' . $fileExtension;
?>
```

Use this as the file name (containing the name and the extension) you are saving to your DB and move the file to a folder.

To delete, the delete.php will pass the filename as a get method or using ajax to send the file name to your delete.php

such that in delete.php, you will then

1. query to delete the file using filename from DB
2. if success, then use the `unlink()` to delete from path such that you do something of this nature

   ```
    <?php unlink(Path_of_uploaded_files/filename); ?>
   ```

I can provide an example later.